# problema con procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con mi procedimiento almacenado el cual aparece por intentar hacer una consulta para llaves foraneas

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_fir(IN pest varchar(50),IN pfir varchar(50),IN pcar varchar(50),IN pemp varchar(50),IN pcc varchar(50))
BEGIN


SELECT id_emp FROM empresas WHERE nom_emp = pemp into @idemp;
SELECT id_estr FROM fac_estructuras WHERE nom_estructura = pest into @idest;

INSERT INTO fac_firmas (`id_fir`,
                        `id_fir_est`,
                        `nom_fir`,
                        `cargo`,
                        `id_fir_emp`,
                        `fir_cc`,
                        `general`) 
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),
        @idest,
        pfir,
        pcar,
        @idemp,
        pcc,
        0);
END //
DELIMITER //
```

El procedimiento se crea correctamente, el problema viene cuando intento meter los parametros, sale este error

1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

lo intente modificando
SELECT id_emp FROM empresas WHERE nom_emp = pemp into @idemp;
SELECT id_estr FROM fac_estructuras WHERE nom_estructura = pest into @idest;

por

```
DECLARE idemp int;
DECLARE idest int;
SET idemp = (SELECT id_emp FROM empresas WHERE nom_emp = pemp);
SET idest = (SELECT id_estr FROM fac_estructuras WHERE nom_estructura = pest);
```

y me sale este error

MySQL ha dicho: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fail

En resumen lo que intento hacer es un INSERT con valores de foraneas como id

Comment: Muestra la definición de las tablas. Ese error ocurre cuando la inserción/actualización viola alguna de las restricciones de la tabla: registros huérfanos, registros duplicados, etc. Puedes ver la constitución de la tablas mediante un `SHOW CREATE TABLE elNombreDeLaTabla;`

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero primero verificar que ambos `SELECT` esten retornando un valor (que no sea `NULL` su resultado); y revisar conforme a la versión de MySQL que usas  las diversas formas de asignar su resultado a una variable ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html ). Por otro lado, el uso de `LAST_INSERT_ID()` revisalo, `id_fir` considero debe ser autoincremento (a mi parecer).

Comment: A.Cedano gracias tenias razon habia un error en la estructura ya lo pude resolver volviendo a crear la tabla